# SQLite multithread - avoid unnecessary blocking for readers

Tags: php, multithreading, sqlite, transactions

Quite a long time ago I wrap all my transactions on **multitread app** (php scripts) that use the same sqlite database into `BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION`. I remember, I read somewhere at SO that: `need to wrap all transactions with`BEGIN IMMEDIATE`on multithread environment to avoid`SQLITE_BUSY` state.

Now, I'm thinking about some optimization.

The Sqlite documentation said: `After a BEGIN IMMEDIATE, no other database connection will be able to write to the database or do a BEGIN IMMEDIATE. Other processes can continue to read from the database, however.`

So, maybe it's safe (or any pitfalls) to only wrap `WRITE` transactions with `IMMEDIATE`? And live `READ` transactions with the default "BEGIN TRANSACTION"? Or maybe to inspect my code and only avoid places where `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` starts, then goes WRITE, then READ, then WRITE etc. and to rewrite this circles like:

```
BEGIN IMMEDIATE
ALL READS
then
ALL WRITES
END
```

If I'm not mistaken in the latter case SQLite will lock whole database only when `WRITE` begin, not when `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` stars? And other threads will be able to read and start there `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deadlock can happen when two transactions want to upgrade their read locks to write locks.
To guarantee that this cannot happen, at least one of those transactions must use `BEGIN IMMEDIATE`.

Read-only transactions are not involved with such deadlocks (they always end without needing more locks), so they can use [BEGIN DEFERRED](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Write-Ahead Logging (WAL). WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently. More about it can be found [here](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

To enable it in your application use `journal mode=WAL` in connection string or `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;`